# node.js mongodb retrieve ISODate format

Tags: node.js, mongodb, date

In mongodb the value of date is:

```
"date" : ISODate("2012-10-11T07:00:00Z")
```

In node with mongoose I retrieve the date and has the following value:

```
entry.date = 2012-10-11T07:00:00.000Z
```

So in my code I do the following:

```
var date = new Date(entry.date);
var format = date.getMonth() + '/' + date.getDate() + '/' + date.getFullYear();
```

I get the output:

```
9/11/2012
```

What is wrong with this?
I would have thought the output would be: `10/11/2012`

I understand the month starts from 0-11 in Date. But since im taking it from a date format
why would I have to minus 1 month from it.

Thanks

Comment: MongoDB/BSON's `ISODate` and JavaScript's `Date` [are equivalent](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/core/document/#date). Note the example for "*Return the month portion of the Date value*" which states that "*months are zero-indexed, so that January is month 0*."

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### JavaScript [`Date.getMonth()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/getMonth) is zero based, not one based.

The "date" variable is a [`Date`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date), not a "date format" as you suspect (JavaScript has no such concept).

```
var dateStr = '2012-10-11T07:00:00.000Z';
var date = new Date(dateStr); // Thu Oct 11 2012 01:00:00 GMT-0600 (MDT)
date.getMonth(); // => 9 (October)
```

Try this instead:

```
var format = (date.getMonth()+1) + //...
```